# Determine d-b if $a^5=b^4,c^3=d^2,c-a=19$ if $a,b,c,d$ are integers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

My Attempt:
Let $a^5=b^4=x^{20}$ and let $c^3=d^2=y^6$. Therefore, $a=x^4$ and $c=y^2$. $ \implies 19 = c-a=y^2-x^4=(y-x^2)(y+x^2)$. Since $a,\ b,\ c,\ d$ are integers, $x,\ y$ are also integers $\implies y-x^2$ and $y+x^2$ are also integers. And since $-x^2<x^2$ for all integers $x$, $y-x^2<y+x^2$.

Therefore there are only two cases:

1) $\ y-x^2=1,\ y+x^2=19$. In this case, x=3 and y=10.

2) $\ y-x^2=-19,\ y+x^2=-1$. This case is not possible since $y+x^2$ is always positive because $y,\ x$ are both positive.

So $b=x^5=3^5=243$ and $d=y^3=1000$. Therefore, $d-b=1000-243=757$.

Is my attempt to the problem correct?

Comment: With the numerical values obtained you can verify whether your answer is correct. I think it is.

Comment: You're solution seems to be OK and it seems to be the only solution to the system of equations. On the other side it might be nice to add why $x$ and $y$ are integers, as it might not be obvious. Anyway you can prove that if $a^n = b^m$ then it is also a $LCM(m,n)$-th power of an integer.

Comment: Basically if you have determine $d-b$ in a way that answers the demands of the question, Even if you guessed them, it's OK. Nothing in the question demanded you to prove nothing regarding to how you got there. You need  only find a number that answers the demands.

Answer (score 2):

The comments basically sum it up, the answer is correct.  And yes, it is the only solution.  The numbers $a$ and $c$ are squares differing by an odd prime, so must be consecutive squares, and $a$ must further be a fourth power.  This forces $a=81=9^2=3^4, c=100=10^2$, which gives the quoted solution only.

Comment: If $a=x^2 \ne c=y^2$ with $y\geq 11$ then $c-a\geq y^2-(|y|-1)^2\geq 11^2-10^2=21>19.$ So we must have $100\geq  y^2=x^2+19.$ And $x^2\in \{0,1,16,81\}$ because $a$ is also  a $4$th power.